# PowerShell Script to get data from Third Party API and insert into database

Tags: sql, mysql, database, powershell

I have created a PowerShell script that will call a REST API and then for each node returned, add the data into a database table. This particular endpoint only returns ~600 records worth of data, however this is the method I will be using for a bunch of other API endpoints.

There are a couple things I think would help with this script:

- Bulk add the records into the database rather than one by one
- For the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only change fields that are different.

My understanding of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` it will check if the ScryId exists, and if it does then update the fields listed below. I would like to only update the fields that are different.

Script:

```
If ( Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SimplySQL ) { Import-Module -Name SimplySQL } Else { Install-Module -Name SimplySQL -Force }

Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
Write-Host "Update Production.Set' Table: " -ForegroundColor Gray -NoNewline
$StartTime = $(Get-Date)

$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.scryfall.com/sets" -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
$ResponseSorted = $Response.data | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "released_at"; Descending = $False}

$username = ""
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

Open-MySQLConnection -Server "" -Port 1234 -Database "Production" -Credential $credential

Foreach ( $Record in $ResponseSorted ) {
    $ScryID = $Record.id
    $Code = Try{ ($Record.code).ToUpper() } Catch {}
    $Name = Try{ ($Record.name) -replace "'","" } Catch {}
    $SetType = $Record.set_type
    $ReleaseDate = $Record.released_at
    $CardCount = $Record.card_count
    $BlockCode = Try{ ($Record.block_code).ToUpper() } Catch {}
    $BlockName = $Record.block
    $ParentSetCode = Try{ ($Record.parent_set_code).ToUpper() } Catch {}
    $Digital = $Record.digital
    $NonFoil = $Record.nonfoil_only
    $Foil = $Record.foil_only
    $Icon = $Record.icon_svg_uri
    $Status = 0

    Invoke-SQLUpdate -query "
        INSERT INTO Production.`Set`
            (ScryID, Code, Name, SetType, ReleaseDate, CardCount, BlockCode, BlockName, ParentSetCode, Digital, NonFoil, Foil, Icon, Status)
        VALUES
            ( '$ScryID', '$Code', '$Name', '$SetType', '$ReleaseDate', $CardCount, '$BlockCode', '$BlockName', '$ParentSetCode', $Digital, $NonFoil, $Foil, '$Icon', $Status )
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            Code = '$Code',
            Name = '$Name',
            SetType =  '$SetType',
            ReleaseDate = '$ReleaseDate',
            CardCount = $CardCount,
            BlockCode = '$BlockCode',
            BlockName = '$BlockName',
            ParentSetCode = '$ParentSetCode',
            Digital = $Digital,
            NonFoil = $NonFoil,
            Foil = $Foil,
            Icon = '$Icon'
    " | Out-Null
}

Close-SQLConnection

$ElapsedTime = $(Get-Date) - $StartTime
$TotalTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}" -f ([datetime]$ElapsedTime.Ticks)
Write-Host $TotalTime -ForegroundColor Cyan
```